# When is $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n \in F) \leq \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i\in F)$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $F$ is a finite set. When does the following hold:
$$
P(X_1,\ldots,X_n \in F) \leq \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i\in F)\ ?
$$

Is it true in general or do we need to impose some further assumptions?

One case where it seems true for instance if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ denotes sampled units without replacement as the right-hand side have more freedom (since the other X_i's takes up a "spot") and hence should be a larger probability. In other words if we could pass to idenpendent $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ with $Y_i \sim X_i$ this would be sufficient. But when is this possible? And how to prove it in for instance the sampling case above.

Comment: $Y_i\sim X_i$ for all $i$ does not tell you that $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n \in F)=P(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n \in F)$.

Comment: The best universal upper bound for $P(A_1\cap \cdots\cap A_n)$ in terms of $P(A_1),\cdots, P(A_n)$ is $P(A_1\cap\cdots \cap A_n)\le\min\{P(A_1),\cdots, P(A_n)\}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No but is would suffice to show $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \leq P(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$

Comment: You may want to play with extreme examples like when $X_1=X_2=\dots=X_n$. A hint toward this direction is that you want something that is far from independent, indeed the inequality would hold if they are independent.

Comment: If your question is about arbitrary random variables, then no, there's no statement like this. You have $=$ when the $\{X_i\}$ variables are an independent collection, and when you don't have independence, you could see $>$ or $<$ in that equation, as others have suggested in the comments. If your question is **really** about sampling with replacement from a finite population, that's a different conversation.